# Android AdMob Position bottom of screen not working

Tags: android, android-layout, admob

Relative layout works but when I do that all my textviews and togglebuttons get throw into the top left corner of the screen please help.

MAIN.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/pattern_carbon_fiber_dark">

<com.google.ads.AdView
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads" 
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
ads:adSize="BANNER"
ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
android:visibility="visible"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_gravity="bottom" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</com.google.ads.AdView>

<TextView android:text="Silent Mode" android:layout_height="wrap_content"           android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TextView>
<ToggleButton android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Silent Mode" android:id="@+id/silentbutton" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textOff="OFF" android:textOn="ON"></ToggleButton>
<TextView android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Wifi "></TextView>
<ToggleButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="ToggleButton" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/wifibutton"></ToggleButton>
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView3" android:text="@string/network" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
<TextView android:layout_gravity="center" android:text="@string/blank" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView4"></TextView>          

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I do a Linear layout the toggle buttons and textviews are fine but the ads then go to the center of the screen. Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: Do a linearlayout where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the android javadoc about linearlayout.setGravity :

public void setGravity (int gravity)

Since: API Level 1
Describes how the child views are positioned. Defaults to GRAVITY_TOP. ***If this layout has a VERTICAL orientation, this controls where all the child views are placed if there is extra vertical space.*** If this layout has a HORIZONTAL orientation, this controls the alignment of the children.
Related XML Attributes

android:gravity
Parameters

gravity See Gravity

---

So it's simply not meant to work with a linear layout. I suggest you either

- change the order of the ad component
- or use a relative layout, then often give much better control on components positionning.

Regards,
Stéphane